# Remove rectangles from Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, polygon, javascript, mapping

I am drawing a Leaflet map.  I also want the ability to add the coordinates via a form.  How is that done?
[leaflet map](https://jsfiddle.net/utf2hwrn/)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Coding questions need the relevant code snippet in the question itself (external links are less likely to be reviewed if not present in the question, and fail over time, irreparably harming the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#rectangle

Your fiddle shows 4 textboxes, just add a button to read the 2 coordinates, then create the polygon and add to the map.

```
// define rectangle geographical bounds
var bounds = [[54.559322, -5.767822], [56.1210604, -3.021240]];
// create an orange rectangle
L.rectangle(bounds, {color: "#ff7800", weight: 1}).addTo(map);
```